# JDOM Transformer - don't contract empty elements

Tags: java, xslt, jdom

I'm using JDOM 2.0.6 to transform an XSLT into an HTML, but I'm coming across the following problem - sometimes the data should be empty, that is, I'll have in my XSLT the following:

```
<div class="someclass"><xsl:value-of select="somevalue"/></div>
```

and when `somevalue` is empty, the output I get is:

```
<div class="someclass"/>
```

which may be perfectly valid XML, but is *not* valid HTML, and causes problems when displaying the resulting page. 
Similar problems occur for `<span>` or `<script>` tags.

So my question is - how can I tell JDOM not to contract empty elements, and leave them as `<div></div>`?

**Edit**
I suspect the problem is not in the actual `XSLTTransformer`, but later when using JDOM to write to html. Here is the code I use:

```
XMLOutputter htmlout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
htmlout.getFormat().setEncoding("UTF-8");

Document htmlDoc = transformer.transform(model);
htmlDoc.setDocType(new DocType("html"));

try (OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outHtml), "UTF-8")) {
    htmlout.output(htmlDoc, osw);
}
```

Currently the proposed solution of adding a zero-width space works for me, but I'm interested to know if there is a way to tell JDOM to treat the document as an HTML (be it in the transform stage or the output stage, but I'm guessing the problem lies in the output stage).

Comment: is the output of the XSLT going back in to a JDOM document (XHTML?)

Comment: No, the output is saved to filesystem and consumed by external applications. If there is a solution which requires passing again through JDOM it is acceptable.

Comment: Do you have `<xsl:output method="html"/>`?

Comment: [According to the w3](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp), the default should be html if the root text is `<html>`, which it is in my case. Anyway - I tried with and without `method=html`, and the results are the same - empty tags get contracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [zero-width-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) between the elements. This doesn't affect the HTML output, but keeps the open-close-tags separated because they have a non-empty content.

```
<div class="someclass">&#8203;<xsl:value-of select="somevalue"/></div>
```

Downside is: the tag is not really empty anymore. That would matter if your output would be XML. But for HTML - which is probably the last stage of processing - it should not matter.

Comment: Thank's for the suggestion. I'll test to see if it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the XML transform is happening directly to a file/stream, and it is no longer in the control of JDOM.

In JDOM, you can select whether the output from the JDOM document has expanded, or not-expanded output for empty elements. Typically, people have output from JDOM like:

```
XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
xout.output(document, System.out);
```

You can modify the output format, though, and [expand the empty elements](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/Format.html#setExpandEmptyElements(boolean))

```
Format expanded = Format.getPrettyFormat().setExpandEmptyElements(true);
XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(expanded);
xout.output(document, System.out);
```

If you 'recover' (assuming it is valid XHTML?) the XSLT transformed xml as a new JDOM document you can output the result with expanded empty elements.

Comment: Thank you. Won't this cause the opposite problem though with elements in HTML that _shouldn't_ be expanded? Or do browsers generally tolerate things like `<br></br>` etc?

Comment: Answer - no, they're not. Now I get the opposite problem with `<br></br>` giving wrong results. So the solution is not yet complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform to a HTML file then consider to use Jaxp `Transformer` with a `JDOMSource` and a `StreamResult`, then the Transformer will serialize the transformation result as HTML if the output method is `html` (either as set in your code or as done with a no-namespace root element named `html`.

Comment: Can you explain how I'd get the `JDOMSource`? In the above example, `model` is a JDOM `Document` which I get from a code I can't change. `transformer` is a JDOM `XSLTTransformer` that I create from a file, so I can control it, but the source XML has to be a JDOM `Document`.

Comment: Ugh, should have looked at the Javadoc first. `JDOMSource` has a constructor which takes a `Document`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the "expandEmptyElements" option, you could create your own writer and pass it to the XMLOutputter:

```
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat().setExpandEmptyElements(true));
StringWriter writer = new HTML5Writer();
outputter.output(document, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

This writer can then modify all HTML5 void elements. Elements like "script" for example won't be touched:

```
private static class HTML5Writer extends StringWriter {

    private static String[] VOIDELEMENTS = new String[] { "area", "base", "br", "col", "command", "embed", "hr",
            "img", "input", "keygen", "link", "meta", "param", "source", "track", "wbr" };

    private boolean inVoidTag;
    private StringBuffer voidTagBuffer;

    public void write(String str) {
        if (voidTagBuffer != null) {
            if (str.equals("></")) {
                voidTagBuffer.append(" />");
                super.write(voidTagBuffer.toString());
                voidTagBuffer = null;
            } else {
                voidTagBuffer.append(str);
            }
        } else if (inVoidTag) {
            if (str.equals(">")) {
                inVoidTag = false;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < VOIDELEMENTS.length; i++) {
                if (str.equals(VOIDELEMENTS[i])) {
                    inVoidTag = true;
                    voidTagBuffer = new StringBuffer(str);
                    return;
                }
            }
            super.write(str);
        }
    }

}
```

I know, this is dirty, but I had the same problem and didn't find any other way.